# Is there a way to check the url of a webview after every click? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make a webview that checks after every click if the url is still the same. If the url is not the same then the app should close. Is this possible with a webview?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a weird way to do it.  Instead, you should just override the WebViewClient's shouldInterceptRequest and shouldOverrideUrlLoading  to disallow any requests to URLs you don't want to allow, so they can't leave your app.

Comment: Let me explain. I want to build a app that opens search.brave.com. I want to search with my app and if i get to the results, i want the app to open the result in a seperate browser. basicly like the google app on android

Comment: Then you'd use the above methods and launch an Intent to view the URL they clicked on.